# TensorFlow map_fn performance and memory use

Tags: tensorflow

I have two implementations of a function that computes the frobenius norm with the trace subtracted. This function is applied to all vectors in dimension 3 of the 4D tensor x. All results are then summed up. I use this as part of a convnet. The version of TensorFlow is 0.9.

My first implementation uses the tf.batch_* functions.

```
def test1(x):
    """x: [batch, height, width, channels]"""
    s = x.get_shape().as_list()
    a = tf.reshape(x, [-1, s[3], 1])
    c = tf.batch_matmul(a, a, adj_y=True)
    c2 = tf.square(c)
    diag = tf.batch_matrix_diag_part(c2)
    return tf.reduce_sum(c2) - tf.reduce_sum(diag)
```

This works but the intermediate tensor c is channels times larger than tensor x which is limiting my batch size. Therefore, i tried a map_fn based approach:

```
def fn(x):
    x1 = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
    c1 = tf.matmul(x1, x1, transpose_b=True)
    c2 = tf.square(c1)
    t1 = tf.trace(c2)
    return tf.reduce_sum(c2)- t1)

def test2(x):
    """x: [batch, height, width, channels]"""
    s = x.get_shape().as_list()
    a = tf.reshape(x, [-1, s[3]])
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.map_fn(fn, a))
```

When I run the second function I get many (50+) messages like:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:244] 
PoolAllocator: After 16084 get requests, put_count=20101
evicted_count=4000 eviction_rate=0.198995 and
unsatisfied allocation rate=0
```

The runtime of test2 is about 45 times longer than the runtime of test1.

With parallel_iterations=10 the memory use for map_fn should be in the order 10 * channels * channels which is much lower than test1.

So the question now is: why does the map_fn approach take longer and why does it seem to be using more memory instead of less?

Comment: I have similar performance issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989489/tensorflow-inference-graph-performance-optimization

Comment: Have you tried tf.scan instead ? or stacking and unstacking / loop yourself ?

Comment: I believe map_fn is forcing you onto the CPU, but I'm having troubles finding the reference where I read that.

Comment: I think this excellent post covers the point here: https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/05/19/Extremely-Stupid-Mistakes-I-made-with-Tensorflow-and-Python/