# tensorflow inference graph performance optimization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensor

I am trying to understand more about certain surprising results i see in implementing a tf graph .
The graph i am working with is just a forest (bunch of trees). This is just a plain forward inference graph , and nothing related to training. I am sharing the snippets for 2 implementation

code snippet 1:

```py
with tf.name_scope("main"):

    def get_tree_output(offset):
        loop_vars = (offset,)
        leaf_indice = tf.while_loop(cond,
                                    body,
                                    loop_vars,
                                    back_prop=False,
                                    parallel_iterations=1,
                                    name="while_loop")
        tree_score = tf.gather(score_tensor, leaf_indice, name="tree-scores")
        output = tf.add(tree_score, output)

    leaf_indices = tf.map_fn(get_tree_output,
                             tree_offsets_tensor,
                             dtype=INT_TYPE,
                             parallel_iterations=n_trees,
                             back_prop=False,
                             name="tree-scores")

    tree_scores = tf.gather(score_tensor, leaf_indices, name="tree-scores")

    output = tf.reduce_sum(tree_scores, name="sum-output")
    output = tf.sigmoid(output, name="sigmoid-output")
```

code snippet 2:

```py
with tf.name_scope("main"):
    tree_offsets_tensor = tf.constant(tree_offsets, dtype=INT_TYPE, name="tree_offsets_tensor")
    loop_vars = (tree_offsets_tensor,)
    leaf_indices = tf.while_loop(cond,
                                 body,
                                 loop_vars,
                                 back_prop=False,
                                 parallel_iterations=n_trees,
                                 name="while_loop")

    tree_scores = tf.gather(score_tensor, leaf_indices, name="tree-scores")

    output = tf.reduce_sum(tree_scores, name="sum-output")
    output = tf.sigmoid(output, name="sigmoid-output")
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same  : the constant tensors , variables, condition and body for the while loop. thread and parallelism was also the same in both case
code snippet2 :  takes about 500 micro sec to do inference 
code snippet 1 : take about  12 milli sec to do inference

The difference is that in snippet 1 , I use `map_fn` to operate on `tree_offset_tensor`, where as in snippet 2 , I get rid of that `map_fn`, and just directly use that tensor, so as I understand in snippet1 `get_tree_output` method gets called with one element from `tree_offset_tensor`, we are  having multiple `while_loop` for each individual offset value, whereas in snippet 2 we just have one `while_loop` that just takes multiple offset values (basically the offset_tensor).

I also tried another variation for snippet , instead of using the map_fn  I write a hand written for loop

code snippet 1 (variation for loop) :

```py
output = 0
with tf.name_scope("main"):
    for offset in tree_offsets:
        loop_vars = (offset,)
        leaf_indice = tf.while_loop(cond,
                                    body,
                                    loop_vars,
                                    back_prop=False,
                                    parallel_iterations=1,
                                    name="while_loop")
        tree_score = tf.gather(score_tensor, leaf_indice, name="tree-scores")
        output = tf.add(tree_score, output)

    #leaf_indices = tf.map_fn(get_tree_output,
    #    tree_offsets_tensor, dtype=INT_TYPE,
    #    parallel_iterations=n_trees, back_prop=False,
    #    name="tree-scores")

    #tree_scores = tf.gather(score_tensor, leaf_indices, name="tree-scores")

    #output = tf.reduce_sum(tree_scores, name="sum-output")
    output = tf.sigmoid(output, name="sigmoid-output")
```

This gives minor improvement :  9 millisec

Comment: I think this excellent post may address the question: https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/05/19/Extremely-Stupid-Mistakes-I-made-with-Tensorflow-and-Python/