# TensorFlow's map_fn only runs on CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I'm running into a weird problem when trying to get TensorFlow's `map_fn` to run on my GPU. Here's a minimal broken example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        def test_func(i):
            return i
        test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5))
        test = sess.run(tf.map_fn(test_func, test_range, dtype=tf.float32))
print(test)
```

This leads to the error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation
>   'map/TensorArray_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification
>   '' because the node was colocated with a group of nodes that required
>   incompatible device '/device:GPU:0' Colocation Debug Info: Colocation
>   group had the following types and devices:  TensorArrayScatterV3: CPU 
>   TensorArrayGatherV3: GPU CPU  Range: GPU CPU  TensorArrayWriteV3: CPU 
>   TensorArraySizeV3: GPU CPU  TensorArrayReadV3: CPU  Enter: GPU CPU 
>   TensorArrayV3: CPU  Const: GPU CPU
>
> Colocation members and user-requested devices:
>   map/TensorArrayStack/range/delta (Const)
>   map/TensorArrayStack/range/start (Const)    map/TensorArray_1
>   (TensorArrayV3)    map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter
>   (Enter) /device:GPU:0   map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArraySizeV3
>   (TensorArraySizeV3)    map/TensorArrayStack/range (Range)
>   map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3 (TensorArrayGatherV3)
>   map/TensorArray (TensorArrayV3)    map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/Enter
>   (Enter) /device:GPU:0   Const (Const) /device:GPU:0
>   map/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3
>   (TensorArrayScatterV3) /device:GPU:0   map/while/TensorArrayReadV3
>   (TensorArrayReadV3) /device:GPU:0
>   map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3 (TensorArrayWriteV3)
>   /device:GPU:0
>
> [[Node: map/TensorArray_1 = TensorArrayV3clear_after_read=true,
>   dtype=DT_FLOAT, dynamic_size=false, element_shape=,
>   identical_element_shapes=true,
>   tensor_array_name=""]]

The code behaves as expected when run on my CPU, and simple operations such as:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        def test_func(i):
            return i
        test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5))
        test = sess.run(tf.add(test_range, test_range))
print(test)
```

work fine on my GPU. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045026/is-there-a-way-to-use-tensorflow-map-fn-on-gpu) seems to describe a similar issue. Does anyone have any tips? The answer on that post implies that `map_fn` should work fine on the GPU. I'm running version 1.8.0 of TensorFlow on Python 3.6.4 on Arch Linux, with CUDA version 9.0 and cuDNN version 7.0 on a GeForce GTX 1050.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error actually stems from the fact that `np.arange` produces `int32`s by default but you specified a `float32` return type. The error is gone with

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        def test_func(i):
            return i
        test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5, dtype=np.float32))
        test = sess.run(tf.map_fn(test_func, test_range, dtype=tf.float32))
print(test)
```

I agree that the error message you got is rather confusing. You get the "real" error message by removing device placement:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
        def test_func(i):
            return i
        test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5))
        test = sess.run(tf.map_fn(test_func, test_range, dtype=tf.float32))
print(test)
# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray dtype is float but Op is trying to write dtype int32.
```