# How to define tf.map_fn with multiple return types on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def test_func(i):
    return i, tf.add(tf.cast(i, tf.float32), 1.2)

test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    test = tf.map_fn(test_func, test_range, dtype=(tf.int32, tf.float32))

sess.run(test)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error. Where am I wrong? My bug is almost exactly similar to [TensorFlow's map_fn only runs on CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845372/tensorflows-map-fn-only-runs-on-cpu) , but with multiple different return types, I get a strange error as shown below

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation map/TensorArray: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '' because the node node map/TensorArray (defined at test.py:13) having device No device assignments were active during op 'map/TensorArray' creation.  was colocated with a group of nodes that required incompatible device '/device:GPU:0'
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices:
TensorArraySizeV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
TensorArrayV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
Range: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
Const: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
TensorArrayGatherV3: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
Enter: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
TensorArrayReadV3: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
TensorArrayScatterV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU
TensorArrayWriteV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU

Colocation members and user-requested devices:
  Const (Const)
  map/TensorArray (TensorArrayV3)
  map/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3 (TensorArrayScatterV3)
  map/TensorArray_1 (TensorArrayV3)
  map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/Enter (Enter) /device:GPU:0
  map/while/TensorArrayReadV3 (TensorArrayReadV3) /device:GPU:0
  map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter (Enter) /device:GPU:0
  map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3 (TensorArrayWriteV3) /device:GPU:0
  map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArraySizeV3 (TensorArraySizeV3)
  map/TensorArrayStack/range/start (Const)
  map/TensorArrayStack/range/delta (Const)
  map/TensorArrayStack/range (Range)
  map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3 (TensorArrayGatherV3)

     [[node map/TensorArray (defined at test.py:13) ]]

No node-device colocations were active during op 'map/TensorArray' creation.
No device assignments were active during op 'map/TensorArray' creation.
```

Comment: Hi, do you solve the question? I also meet the problem...

Comment: @nwpuxhld I guess I got around it by converting my int to float. It has something to do with low level kernels on GPU. When pushing the calculation commands to GPU, I think GPUs can't handle int and float in same block or compartment or something which is why it runs on CPU but not on GPU. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using the cpu. My computer has a GPU.

I do not know the reason...

The modified code is

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np


    def test_func(i):
        return tf.cast(i, tf.int32), tf.add(tf.cast(i, tf.float32), 1.2)

    test_range = tf.constant(np.arange(5))

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        test = tf.map_fn(test_func, test_range, dtype=(tf.int32, tf.float32))

    sess.run(test)
```