# Tensorflow: Dataset Map With num_parallel_calls Offers No Speedup

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using TensorFlow and the `tf.data.Dataset` API to perform some text preprocessing.  Without using `num_parallel_calls` in my `dataset.map` call, it takes 0.03s to preprocess 10K records.

When I use `num_parallel_trials=8` (the number of cores on my machine), it also takes 0.03s to preprocess 10K records.

I googled around and came across this: [Parallelism isn't reducing the time in dataset map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484689/parallelism-isnt-reducing-the-time-in-dataset-map)

where they indicate that you need to use TensorFlow operations to see a speedup.  Here's the thing: I *am* using only TensorFlow operations.  Specifically, I'm mapping this function:

```
def preprocess(self, x, data_table):
    x['reviews'] = tf.string_split(x['reviews'], delimiter=' ')
    x['reviews'] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(x['reviews'], default_value=' ')
    x['reviews'] = tf.cast(data_table.lookup(x['reviews']), tf.int32)
    nbatch = tf.cast(tf.shape(x['reviews'])[0], tf.int32)
    nseq = tf.cast(tf.shape(x['reviews'])[1], tf.int32)
    padding = tf.cond(tf.less(nseq, 100),
                      lambda: 0 * tf.ones([nbatch, 100 - nseq], tf.int32),
                      lambda: 0 * tf.ones([nbatch, 0], tf.int32))
    x['reviews'] = tf.concat((x['reviews'], padding), axis=1)[:, :100]
    x['reviews'].set_shape([None, 100])
    return x
```

Any idea why I don't see any speedup?

Thanks!

Comment: There can be many reasons but I see is that the two operations `sparse_tensor_to_dense` and `lambda` functions as the bottleneck here. But to investigate further, you should provide more details what you want to achieve and how exactly your dataset and pipeline looks

Comment: Is `preprocess()` the function that you pass to `Dataset.map()`? (Asking because I wouldn't expect `data_table` to be an argument in a map function.) As mlRocks suggests, it would be helpful to see the larger context of the input pipeline. For example, if your input data are on a slow storage system, you might have an I/O bottleneck that no amount of parallelism in the `map()` will recover.

Answer (score 0):

My first assumption would be the calls to lambda are crushing your speed as lazy initialization for each iteration and core.   According to this url he has a similar problem to speed and core use . [Is there a way to use tensorflow map_fn on GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045026/is-there-a-way-to-use-tensorflow-map-fn-on-gpu) 
I am pretty much a beginner with tensor and piping but I’ll look into later when I have access to computer,  I would like to know what executables are being run where though.